# how to know the full link address from a youtube packet

Tags: wireshark

In wireshark capture, I can get the ip address from the ethernet header, but how I get additional information about the access?

For example, suppose I have tried to access the page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5v1JnYv_yWs from a browser.

From the ethernet packet header I can see that the ip address for youtube.com (actually google) has been accessed. But how do I get the full link information? What filters do I have to apply, which fields do I need to look at?

Comment: Did you try right click on the packet and follow stream? at the beginning you will likely have an http get request with the uri.

Comment: I tried to follow the stream, but not able to get the information. Can you give a detailed answer with some screenshots, to show how exactly to locate this information?

Comment: Also, I dont see any HTTP GET packets. All I see are DNS,TCP, and UDP packets. So I am not sure where to get the information from.

Comment: it was just a guess. I don't actually know, thus only a comment. also http get would be a tcp packet. http get is after all an http message, thus on layer 7 protocol. I don't think you can find out the video url from the video packets. the http request tells the server which video to fetch and it will them just shove it down the socket. thus only the initial http request will have the url.

Answer (score 0):

You will not see it since it's HTTPS and encrypted.